# Kernel current working directory and inode information placement

Tags: kernel, process, inode, cwd

I'm reading some doc about UNIX but I don't understand two things:

- Why is important for the kernel to know the current working directory of the running process?
- Why not keeping the inode information in the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system needs to keep track of the current directory of all processes because otherwise processes couldn't use relative paths for anything (including for example file open or stat, and changing directories — what does `chdir("..")` mean if you don't track were the process currently sits?).

There's also the matter that without tracking that info, the kernel wouldn't be able to check if a process is sitting inside a given mount point. So you'd be liable to accidentally unmount a filesystem from under a process, leading to inconsistent state.

For your second question: think about hard links. They would be much harder to implement correctly and safely if the inode data was in the directory "structure" itself. Much easier to have essentially pointers to the inodes in the directory structure, makes adding or removing links to a given inode pretty simple.